# How to check image width and height before upload image in uploadify?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

**Below is the uploadify plugins , here I want to use code for validate image dimension(width and height) before upload.**

```
<script>
$(function() {
$("#file_upload_1").uploadify({
height        : 30,
swf           : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
uploader      : '/uploadify/uploadify.php',
width         : 120
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Side note: Never trust the client! Do not rely on verifications performed on the client side but check the size on the server (at least double check it there). What you _could_ possibly do: Create an `IMG`-DOM element, assign the source image, and measure it after layout. With swf, this won't work though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploadify Minimum Image Width And Height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942790/uploadify-minimum-image-width-and-height)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the size of the image on this line:

```
$size = getimagesize($pathToFullImage);
```

Why not add a conditional here to check if it is at least the size you want, and if not return an error.

```
if($size[0] > 150 || $size[1] > 150) {
  return $someError;
}
```

Also it looks like there is an onError option for Uploadify which you could set:
[http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/](https://github.com/RonnieSan/uploadify)

**EDIT:** This thread looks like it could be of some help to you:
[http://www.uploadify.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=14](https://github.com/RonnieSan/uploadify)